# custom tableview with only image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a default tableview style with 4 entries and would like to customize it show only 4 large image.
Is possible custom table view or i must use another method?

[image: custom tableview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have such a display (a menu like, not a table like) I use simple buttons with the following properties:

- Type: Custom
- Background: an image in .PNG format since it supports transparency and I can do a nice layout with it.

I either set the Title of the button if it doesn't ruin the design, or I add labels under the buttons to explain what they do. In the `TouchUpInside` event of the buttons I push the view that I want using a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ONLY using four images, consider using a typical `UIViewController` and laying out the objects in the nib file.

Comment: Instead of 4 cell i would display 4 image and when touch one image go to next subtable.